# Error installing ruby 3.2.1 BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build) with dependencies already installed

Tags: ruby, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install ruby 3.2.1 in my wsl, im using rbenv installed through homebrew, when i try `rbenv install 3.2.1` i got this:

```
Installing ruby-3.2.1...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
ruby-build: using libyaml from homebrew
ruby-build: using gmp from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build 20230615)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20230628033452.57435.3mGe1n
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20230628033452.57435.log

Last 10 log lines:
Try running `apt-get install -y libssl-dev` to fetch missing dependencies.

Configure options used:
  --prefix=/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/readline
  --with-libyaml-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/libyaml
  --with-gmp-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gmp
  LDFLAGS=-L/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/include
```

I already run `apt-get install -y libssl-dev` but that doesn't solve it, what i missing?

The mos relevant log part is:

```
installing bundled gem cache:       /home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/cache
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Try running `apt-get install -y libssl-dev` to fetch missing dependencies.

Configure options used:
  --prefix=/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/readline
  --with-libyaml-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/libyaml
  --with-gmp-dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gmp
  LDFLAGS=-L/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/home/cristian/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/include
```

I trying  `apt-get install -y libssl-dev` and `sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev`

Comment: As you are not listing which dependencies you installed for this, did you install all of these dependencies: `sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev` as advised by https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment

Answer (score 0):

I install Ruby 3.2.2 success by using homebrew
steps:

> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
> (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /home/$USER/.bashrc
> eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> brew doctor
> brew install ruby